# WebRequest content-disposition missing

Tags: vb.net, webrequest

Got me a little problem which has me stumped.
So, this is a little program I wrote some years ago when learning, has done it's job flawlessly since up until a few days ago.  Essentially, just hist a SOAP service and downloads a file.

```
httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(My.Settings.RequestAddress)

Using httpResponse As WebResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse
    Using responseStream = New IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream, StreamEncoding)

        Dim SourceFileName As String = GetSourceFileName(httpResponse.Headers.GetValues("content-disposition"))
        'httpResponse.Headers.GetValues("content-disposition") is returning nothing

        Dim StreamFileName As String = IO.Path.Combine("c:\Temp", SourceFileName)
        Using StreamWrite = New IO.StreamWriter(StreamFileName, False, StreamEncoding)
            Do While Not responseStream.EndOfStream
                StreamWrite.WriteLine(responseStream.ReadLine)
            Loop
            StreamWrite.Flush()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using

Private Function GetSourceFileName(ByVal dispositionAttrib As String) As String
    Dim retVal As String = String.Empty
    Dim strArr As String() = Split(dispositionAttrib, "=")
    If strArr.Length > 1 Then
        retVal = strArr(1)
    End If
    Return retVal
End Function
```

For what ever reason I can not for the life of me figure out, the "content-disposition" header attribute is not visible.
I can make the exact same calls via postman and it's there.  Have stepped through and inspected the Header.Keys collection as well, no sign of it.  What am I missing?

**Update**
Just as a bit of a trial, changed the WebRequest to HttpClient.  Still missing the content-disposition

```
Using client As New HttpClient()
    Dim response = client.GetAsync(My.Settings.RequestAddress).Result
    Dim fileNameAttribute = response.Headers.GetValues("content-disposition")
    Console.WriteLine(fileNameAttribute)
End Using
```

**Update**  Response.Header value I'm getting when viewing via debugger is:

> {Pragma: no-cache Content-Length: 27 Cache-Control: private
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Date: Wed, 02 Sep 2020 20:45:37
> GMT Expires: Tue, 01 Sep 2020 20:45:38 GMT Set-Cookie:
> ASP.NET_SessionId=0kqeh5d1a2fni35chmbpibqv; path=/; HttpOnly;
> SameSite=Lax Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> }

I'm wondering about that blank line at the bottom after the X-Powered-By

Comment: `Headers.GetValues()` returns a string array, not a string and it's not mandatory. But, since you see it in Postman... Read it as just `httpResponse.Headers("Content-Disposition")`. Also, change `dim httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(My.Settings.RequestAddress)` and `Using httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(httpRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)` -- How did you determine the `StreamEncoding` before reading the Stream (did you compare with `httpResponse.CharacterSet`)?

Comment: @Jimi, all valid comments, but poor coding aside.  Have changed to httpResponse.Headers("Content-Disposition") but still returning nothing.  On the Encoding, honestly can not remember how I got to UTF-8, but that is the character set I'm getting in the response

Comment: For anyone interested, still no solution to missing "content-disposition" but with a few upstream changes I've reworked the solution to use temporary file name which seems to have everything up and going again